# Most secure way to implement a file server to avoid ransomware

Tags: linux, windows, network-share, file-sharing

Hi I'm looking to migrate several large file servers off of windows 2012.  Servers are mainly just serving flat .pdf, word files, on internal network mainly running windows 10 clients .  I am strongly considering moving to Centos / Fedora Linux for stability, snap-shoting, and security.  What are the best practices regarding securing these servers against ransomware and authenticating against windows.  Do I have to go with samba or would nfs be more secure.  Any wisdom is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Biggest improvement is backups to **offine/disconnected** destinations.

Comment: This is not a properly asked question but I don't believe in down-voting people for stuff like this. ... You haven't said a thing about the clients using the system, what they need, or even if they're on an internal network or external one. ... You really need to properly describe your existing setup and how you would like it to look when you're done.

Comment: @RichardT edited as per your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a specific question but there are two important points that mitigate most ransomware attacks:

1 - Always have an off-site, offline backup of your data (probably rotate two or more)

2 - Make sure your data is encrypted so if the server is compromised your data is not.

How you do this depends on too many variables to go into here.

Comment: Just a small thing to add here. You should know about amount of data you are ready to lose in such cases. I mean RPO (Recovery Point Objective) is thing you should be aware of. This will lead you to the answer on how often to do off-site/offline backups.